# Новая версия программы для Android

Tags: android, android-studio

У меня есть моя программа написанная для Android. Теперь я задумался о написании новой версии этой программы, но при этом я не хочу забрасывать исправление ошибок или дополнение каких то мелких фич в старой версии на то время что я пишу новую версию. То есть как я понимаю в одном проекте у меня должно жить несколько версий программы. Мне необходимо просто создать новый модуль в проекте или есть какой то более правильный путь?

Comment: надо использовать систему управления версиями и создавать ветку для новой версии, если что нужно исправить, нужно будет откатываться в релиз-ветку и делать изменения, после чего благополучно вернуться к новой версии и продолжать ее разрабатывать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте систему контроля версии(например git)? Если да, то используйте разные ветки. Можно посмотреть в сторону Git Flow [gitflow](https://habrahabr.ru/post/106912/)